# Restart a powershell script if closed?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Im starting a powershell script using a bat file when the computer starts. But I need to make it restart in case someone closes it or crashes...

So far I invoke the script using:

```
powershell.exe -window minimized -noexit -file "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\UNB\script\UNBILLING.ps1"
```

But how can I do the restart when it closes?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: have another script start it, monitor that it is running, and restart if it if stops.

Comment: Another option can be a recurring single-instance scheduled task, but restart will not happen instantly.

Comment: Does the script ask for user input?

Comment: No it doesnt ask for user input. It will just start when the computer does it.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 64-bit. Powershell 5

Move all of this from the windows startup folder to a [hidden](https://www.howtogeek.com/tips/how-to-run-a-scheduled-task-without-a-command-window-appearing/) / background / non-interactive scheduled task that runs at logon.

Use `unbilling.ps1` to [create](https://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/file-create-2/) a placemark file just before it exits.

```
New-Item -Path $env:temp -Name "UnbillingPs1Finished.txt" -ItemType File -force
exit
```

In the batch test if the text file exists and if not run unbilling.ps1

```
:loop
if not exist %temp%\UnbillingPs1Finished.txt (
powershell.exe -window minimized -noexit -file "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\UNB\script\UNBILLING.ps1"
goto :loop
)
del %temp%\UnbillingPs1Finished.txt
```

Comment: I was thinking of a prompt windows in case you press the X in the batch file window... but seems tricky too, your solution could work.

Comment: @jua updated answer. you did not say you wanted to check if the batch file had run.  Is  there a way to keep a batch file from being closed?